# What to name a section at the end of thesis containing original material for future development?

Tags: thesis, writing, writing-style

I have written my master thesis. The last chapter is "Summary and Conclusions". After this chapter which ends the thesis, I want to add a specific note of my own. It is a new idea which needs lengthy explanation and it does not **directly** relate to the contents of the thesis. It is a new algorithm which is not used in the thesis but I want to introduce this algorithm for future development of the field.

I want to know under which section I have to write it. Should I write it as an appendix? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds a question for your thesis advisor.

Comment: If it does not relate to the thesis, why do you want to include it?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft thanks for your reply. I have edited the question. I have mentioned that it is not **dircetly** related. It is a new algorithm which is not used in the thesis but I want to introduce this algorithm for future development of the field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's related to the ideas in the theses, then it sounds like a "future directions" subjection in "Summary and Conclusions."

If it's really not related at all, then it should go in a different paper.

Comment: The calculations in the thesis are based on old algorithms. This section which I want to add introduces a new algorithm which is not used through out the thesis and no one else has done any calculation with this aforementioned algorithm. Therefore I cannot include it in the  main body of the thesis, since I cannot site to any published work.

Comment: @Yousof Then it definitely sounds like "future directions" to me.